# InvocationTargetException with target: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I am receiving:

> InvocationTargetException with target:
> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.util.NoSuchElementException.

The exception is thrown on:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "AliveTest")
    @WebResult(name = "AliveTestAcknowledgement", targetNamespace = "http://.../AfterSalesPackageCatalogueService/V2")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "ProcessAliveTest", targetNamespace = "http://.../V2", className = "com....aftersalespackagecatalogueservice.v2.ProcessAliveTestType")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "AcknowledgeAliveTest", targetNamespace = "http://.../AfterSalesPackageCatalogueService/V2", className = "com.....aftersalespackagecatalogueservice.v2.AcknowledgeAliveTestType")
    public AliveTestAcknowledgementType AliveTest()
        throws Fault
    ;
```

The response object comes properly.

Comment: these multiple dots look suspicious

Comment: @m.antkowicz These dots are to just hide whole namespace, but this is correct.

Comment: which JDK version you are using?

Comment: as javax package is removed from JDK 9 and above. So you need to try with lower version(JDK 8) else explicitly add javax dependency in your project.

Comment: @hiteshbedre I use java 8